# ListView WinForms Bind to ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Is it possible to bind an ObservableCollection to a ListView in Winforms? All the examples I'm seeing are for WPF but I can't find anything for Winforms.

Ideally I'd like to bind the following:

```
ObservableCollection<List> accounts = new ObservableCollection<List>();
accounts.add("someuser");
accounts.add("someotheruser");
```

... to the ListView. Using an ObservableCollection (as can be done in WPF) so that any changes to the ObservableCollection will cause the ListView to update.

Here's what I've tried - taking a stab in the dark ...

```
groups.Add(new Group
{
    title = "Mathematics Group",
    id = "034234",
    members = "54"
});

listViewGroups.CheckBoxes = true;
listViewGroups.Columns.Add("checkbox", "");
listViewGroups.Columns.Add("groupid", "Group ID");
listViewGroups.Columns.Add("groupname", "Group Name");

listViewGroups.DataBindings.Add("groupname", groups, "title");
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try it to see if it's possible?

Comment: I tried through guesswork. I tried to find examples online using Winforms but wasn't able to find anything. Poking around in the dark really hence why my last resort was to ask here.

Comment: For WinForms, I think you're better off using BindingList<T>.

Comment: Entity Framework contains a [`ToBindingList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696575%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) extension method for `ObservableCollection` that may be enough here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible but you may need to use some external library that provides `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You can use `PostSharp` for that.

Answer (score 2):

Very late answer, but for future reference.

ListView in .NET WinForms does *not* support data binding.

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-bind-a-dataset-to-an-objectlistview) -- an open source enhancement wrapper around a ListView -- does.